# Laravel the right way for Many to Many table structure

Tags: php, laravel, migration, table-structure

I'm having a many to many relation. Lets say that I have Many users that can be in Many groups and the other way around.

I wan't to make a table that contains the following columns

**group_user**

***id / name / user_id / group_id***

Since I have only 3 groups Junior, Middle and Senior I don't want to make another separated table for them. My idea here is to make the following approach:

1. Creating 3 records in the same table group_user with the following data

***id / name / user_id / group_id***

**1 / Junior / null / null**

**2 / Middle / null / null**

**3 / Senior / null / null**

So now when I want to insert a group_id I will use this 3 ID's that I just created with NULL user_id and group_id.

My records will look something like this:

***id / name / user_id / group_id***

**4 / NULL / 125 / 1 -> The id of the Junior group that is in the same table.**

**5 / NULL / 125 / 3 -> The id of the Senior group that is in the same table.**

```
Is this a valid way to do it? How wrong it is?
```

Comment: Create a separate table for the metadata of the 3 groups because what you are doing here contains inapplicable nulls which are not allowed in a normalised relational database. (Inapplicable NULL is a null that can never have a value under any circumstances)

Comment: This makes sense! Thanks a lot I will read more for "Inapplicable NULL", thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend following the correct procedures as follows:

Table 1 users table:
id | name

Table 2 groups table:
id | name

Table 3 group_user pivot table:
id | user_id | group_id

Note: Table 3 should never hold a nullable value

The relation would be as follows, right now we have two models, a User model and a Group model.

both will have a belongsToMany relation towards each other.

Here is the method you will use in the User model:

```
public function groups()
{
    $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

And here is the method you will use in the Group model:

```
public function users()
{
    $this->belongsToMany(Group::class);
}
```

This is the recommended way to continue.

Comment: I will definitely take this way. I was thinking that It's stupid to have a table with 3 records in it. But it's even worst to have a table with denormalizated data in the table. Thanks a lot for the answer and the spend time to write it :)

Comment: no no, it wasn't stupid of you to think of it that way, I know it doesn't make much sense, but you will see that this will flow very naturally inside your application. Update me on how it goes.